# How to set background color of particular column's items of gridview in android?

Tags: android, gridview

I have created a custom calendar using `GridView`. Now I want to set background color of weekends(i.e. Saturday,Sunday).

I want to know, how we can get a particular column and its items of `GridView`?

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter you have `getView()` method that return the item view, you can use it to change the view background depending on position.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if(position == SUNDAY || position == SATURDAY){
     // weekends background
  } else{
     // default background
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**:

Since you have dates in your model, you can use the **Calendar** to check if its Weekend or not:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.setTime(yourDate);
 int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

  if(dayOfWeek == 1 /*for SUNDAY*/|| dayOfWeek == 7 /*for SATURDAY*/){
     // weekends background
  } else{
     // default background
  }

}
```

PS: Week is from 1->7 for Sun->Sat

Comment: Thanks....I have set weekdays name in different layout in this grid view  I have only weekdays with dates only not weekday's name.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it by defining position og grids

```
if(position==1){ // item's position that you want to change background color
        [VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_BACKGROUND].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
        // Set other item's background color to default background color you want
        [VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_BACKGROUND].setBackgroundColor(Color.[WHAT_COLOR_YOU_WANT]);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

suppose u have a grid of3*3 then set it like

```
if(position==2 || position==3){
[VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_BACKGROUND].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}elseif(position==5 || position==6){
[VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_BACKGROUND].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}elseif(position==8 || position==9){
[VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_BACKGROUND].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}else{
     [VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_CHANGE_BACKGROUND].setBackgroundColor(Color.[WHAT_COLOR_YOU_WANT]); }
```